# MahApps Metro how to bind DropDownMenu to parent DataGrid property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a `DataGrid` and one of the columns is a template column which contains `DropDownMenu` from MahApps Metro. I successfully populate `ItemsSource` and items are displayed when menu is clicked.

I'm having problem now binding this selected value to datagrid items source.

I've tried so far:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton ItemsSource="{Binding ResTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Content="{Binding Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And whenever I select an item, the value doesn't even change on `DropDownMenu`, like it item can't even be selected.

How could I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `DropDownButton` has no concept of selection. You should use a `SplitButton` and bind its `SelectedItem` property to your source property.

The built-in `DataGrid` has no `Type` property though so it's unclear to what property you are trying to bind. Make sure that the type of the items in the `ResTypes` collection is the same as the `Type` property that you are trying to bind to.